# Groovy pointer to list

Tags: groovy

As I'm totally new to Groovy I have this problem I don't know how to solve:
I wan't to get a new value from a list, which list is depending of the value of the input string:
Simplified Example:

```
class NewStringValue
{

    def getValue (inpList)
    {
        def list1 = ["L1V1","L1V2","L1V3"];
        def list2 = ["L2V1","L2V2","L2V3","L2V4"];
        def worklist =  Here is my problem, how do I get Worklist to point to the correct list according to the value in InpList, see calling ex. below?


     def i = 0;
     def j = worklist.size-1;

     while (i<=j)
      {
      // some code.......
         newValue = worklist[i];
      }
     return newValue;}
```

Example of calling above

```
value = getValue("list1")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map, and look up the values based on the key passed in:

```
class NewStringValue {
    def getValue(inpList) {
        def lookup = [
            list1: ["L1V1","L1V2","L1V3"],
            list2: ["L2V1","L2V2","L2V3","L2V4"]
        ]

        def worklist = lookup[inpList]
        def newValue = ''
        worklist.each {
            newValue += it
        }
        newValue
    }
}

new NewStringValue().getValue('list2')
```